# svn lock branch

Tags: svn

can i block commit operation possibility to selected branch

Comment: http://www.noah.org/wiki/SVN_Directory_Lock has a perfect solution for locking branches using the `pre-commit` hook

Answer (score 6):

If you can edit the authz file of your repository you can make a branch readonly

```
# [repository:/baz/fuz]
# @harry_and_sally = rw
# * = r
```

Answer (score 0):

If you control the server, set up a pre-commit hook.