# How to lock a folder in SVN - with tortoiseSVN client

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have couple of folders in SVN which I want to lock from other users to avoid accidental commit , I know we can lock files but looking for an option to lock a folder , I am using tortoiseSVN (TortoiseSVN 1.9.7, Build 27907 - 64 Bit , 2017/08/08 19:34:38)

Any idea ?

Comment: Right-click folder->Tortoise SVN->Get lock... doesn't work for you?

Comment: no that I already tried,  it will lock only files

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why aren't you doing this with account privileges (giving them only read-access) instead of locking?

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to lock a directory within SVN ([see here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.locking.html)). Therefore, TortoiseSVN cannot offer this option.
You could take a look at path based access control http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html
Or this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26743077/3809520) which describes a python script to create a similar behavior.