# Achieving svn lock on entire branch using 'svn lock' sort of a command

Tags: svn, locking, branch

Is there a way to lock entire branch with svn lock command ?.

Locking files/directories individually doesnot help. And I want to achieve without modifying server side 'authz'.

Let me know, if anybody knows such an options exists.

Related Q is here: [svn lock branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064229/svn-lock-branch/13491857#13491857)

My trial way:

svn lock http://{Repo-path}/branch_name

Resulted in :

svn: E160017: '/branch_name' is not a file in filesystem

Answer (score 2):

Branch is basically a directory. And according to docs, there is no support for locking directories, yet.

["Subversion does not currently allow locks on directories."](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.locking.html#idp8375600)

Answer (score 0):

Not possible without server-side modification as posted above.

If you are willing to modify the `pre-commit.tmpl` or `pre-commit` script in your repository's `hooks` directory (and you might need to install the `pexpect` Python package if not working on Debian) then use **Noah Spurrier**'s SVN directory locking [script](http://www.noah.org/wiki/SVN_Directory_Lock). Worked **perfectly** for me with a minimum of tweaking.